# How can I open this door?

Tags: genshin-impact

In the Sumeru desert there is a hole in the sand directly to the west of the Mausoleum of King Deshret.

[image: map]

If you drop down the hole you are presented with what appears to be a large triangular door.

[image: picture of door]

I've explored a fair bit of the mausoleum and subterranean desert but I've yet to find a way of opening it. **Is it currently possible to open this door, and if so, how?**

Comment: Actually, there are two of those doors. One of them, you will have to open from the other side. There is another entrance, via the mausoleum. I found it while searching for sacred seals I was missing. The other door, I haven't figured it out yet. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 3):

> That door is actually a story domain from a quest that probably you didn't start yet. Ignore it, you will get there when the story wants you to. It is similar to the Sal Terrace sigil that you can only unlock during a specific character quest.

Comment: I'd recommend following 3 quests to unlock most of the desert. Arcon quest, King Deshret and the Three Magi, and two world quests, Golden Slumber and Dual Evidence.

Comment: I don't think you need to put this answer under a spoiler tag. It isn't really spoiling any story details. It doesn't even say which quest in particular involves this door.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

No one can solve it yet until this very day. I have complete the whole desert by 100% and all the main quest and side quest itself even but none of it related to open the door. You need 4 fire wisps and I can only find 3 of them.

Completing all the quest DOES NOT help you open the door.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, this was for one of the main quests where we find one of the previous general Mahamatra's (if I remember correctly, but it might've been a priest) tomb and we resolve with one of king deshret's believers. It's not uncommon for the fire thingies to be missing, there are plenty of other places where it bugged me the hell out

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/322836)