# How to open this door in Sumeru?

Tags: genshin-impact

[image: door]

[image: map]

I can't find the way to enter this ruin. Please help

Comment: What have you tried? Is it maybe tied to a specific quest?

Comment: Related to this question, as I would imagine the answer will be the same https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/399606/how-can-i-open-this-door

Comment: Have you tried using elemental sight on it to confirm that it is a working door? They should show up white

Comment: I checked the location out. Elemental Sight does show it to be a working door, so it's probably not a domain. There were two mirages on either side of the door, and touching them spawned enemies but seemed to do nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

The door can only be opened from the other side. The [Teyvat Interactive Map](https://act.hoyolab.com/ys/app/interactive-map/index.html) shows that the entrance is found south of this location, just west of the southern edge of The Dune of Magma pyramid:

[image: image of underground area connected to the door]