# How do I open this door?

Tags: genshin-impact

I found a door that seems possible to open while exploring Sumeru, I don't remember any quest involving this door and I didn't find any puzzles nearby. Does anyone know if it is possible to open this door and if so, how?

Additional information: I *think* I've done all the quests that don't involve a daily mission.

[image: the door appears to have the same mechanism as the other doors that actually open.]

[image: this is the place]

Comment: [Related?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/399606/124566) or maybe [this one too?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/399871/124566)

Comment: I found an old post about it and some say it's not supposed to be unlocked, others say it's part of Dehya's story which I haven't played yet so I can't confirm [reddit post1](https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact/comments/10ztutc/34_how_to_open_the_new_door_near_khajnisut/)
and others saying it's an exit and the entrance isn't too far away from there but maybe use the interactive map to find it easier [reddit post2](https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact/comments/10s8vgf/help_how_do_you_enter_this_place_this_is_slightly/) I think it's most likely part of the story quest, did you play it?

Answer (score 3):

Like Mai original comment suggested that is indeed the entrance to a domain called ["Bygone Glories Passed"](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Bygone_Glories_Passed) that you will visit [during Dehya story quest.](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Sincerity%27s_Facade)

If you are still unsure, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G44fFZkKQ9Y) clearly shows the player entering the domain.

Note: don't worry, luckily the place doesn't contain any [Hydro Slime.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dehyamains/comments/114qq6y/did_they_really_just_showcased_dehya_failing_to/)